# How to style background of full component?

Tags: css, angularjs, colors, background, background-color

How can I change the *color-background* of a full component?

100% color of full width and height of the component.

I used body but It didn't work. I need to place all the components in a `div` and then *style* them?

Comment: consider providing some code what you've tried so far.

Comment: Wrap your component html template in div and give background color to that div. Hope it helps you !

Comment: Send you code so far what it you did.

Comment: You issue is not clear without any code that produces result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the outermost element of the component's template and style the background for that class.